# Send email based on form boolean value

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to send email based on the form boolean value.
If the Trigger_Email is True then send the mail

Below is the models.py

```
class New_Shipment(models.Model):
    Status_CHOICES = (
        ("1", "Open"),
        ("2", "Close"),

    )

    alphanumeric = RegexValidator(r'^[\s0-9a-zA-Z\.-_]*$', 'Only alphanumeric characters are allowed.')
    Courier_or_Freight_details = models.CharField(max_length=200, validators=[alphanumeric])
   
    Quantity = models.IntegerField()
    Action_On = models.CharField(max_length=200, validators=[alphanumeric])
    Status = models.CharField(max_length=300, validators=[alphanumeric], choices=Status_CHOICES)
    Trigger_Email = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Below is my views.py

```
def my_form1(request, new_shipment=New_Shipment):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form1 = MyForm1(request.POST)
        if form1.is_valid():
            new_shipment = get_object_or_404(New_Shipment)
        elif new_shipment.Trigger_Email:
            subject = "New Shipment Details"
            message = "Hello \n New Shipment details added to the EPC\n\n Regards,\nIsmail"
            from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            to_list = ['toemail@gmail.com']
            send_mail(subject, message, from_email, to_list, fail_silently=True)


            form1.save()
            return HttpResponse('Submitted successfully')
            # return redirect('/home_page/')
    else:
        form1 = MyForm1()
    return render(request, "authentication/New_shipment.html", {'form1': form1})
```

url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('signup', views.signup, name="signup"),
    path('activate/<uidb64>/<token>', views.activate, name='activate'),
    path('signin', views.signin, name="signin"),
    path('Monthly_Shipment', views.Monthly_Shipment, name="Monthly_Shipment"),
    path('signout', views.signout, name="signout"),
    path('home_page', views.home_page, name="home_page"),
    url(r'form1', views.my_form1, name='form1'),
    path('View_New_shipment', views.View_New_shipment, name="View_New_shipment"),
]
```

Any Kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Change `elif` to `if` inside `form1.is_valid()` condition.

Instead:

```
    if form1.is_valid():
        new_shipment = get_object_or_404(New_Shipment)
    elif new_shipment.Trigger_Email:
        subject = "New Shipment Details"
        ...
```

Do this:

```
    if form1.is_valid():
        new_shipment = get_object_or_404(New_Shipment)
        if new_shipment.Trigger_Email:
            subject = "New Shipment Details"
            ...
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the quick response, I tried with your solution but I am getting the error 
"Page not found (404)

No New_Shipment matches the given query."

Comment: So `get_object_or_404(New_Shipment)` gives you 404, it does not find the object. You need to check what value you are passing in here: `def my_form1(request, new_shipment=New_Shipment)`.

Comment: From models.py the model name New_Shipment I want to get the value of Trigger_Email weather it is true or false if it is true then send Email

Comment: I know what you are trying to do, but you didn't provide what do you pass as `New_Shipment`. You need to share `urls.py`. Btw. always declare specified attributes in `get_object_or_404`, like `get_object_or_404(id=New_Shipment)`. Another thing is, that decalring: `new_shipment=New_Shipment` and later using `New_Shipment` instead of `new_shipment` is weird and makes no sense at all.

Comment: Updated my url.py. Actually I am new to this just trying and checking some methods. Can you please let me know how can i pass the Trigger_Email field. Thanks

Comment: In this line you don't pass any parameter: `url(r'form1', views.my_form1, name='form1')`. So you cannot simply put it as view's argument. Please, finish your tutorial, because you are doing fundamental mistakes.